# SQLite + SQLCipher + FMDatabase on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm currently using FMDatabase in my iOS app and I'm very happy with it.
I plan to encrypt the sqlite database with SQLCipher.

Here are my questions:

1) Are FMDatabase and SQLCipher compatibles ? I think I just need to add a new method in FMDatabase called openEncrypted...and do the job for SQLCipher. I hope all FMDatabase methods will work.

2) Actually, I have 2 databases in my app. Then I do an ATTACH DATABASE in my app to join them. I would like to encrypt just one of the two. Will it work or I need to encrypt the 2 databases ? (One is critical, the other is not)

3) I don't really understand what I will have to provide to Apple (documents) if I encrypt these files.

Thanks you !

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes, its easy just override the "open" methods to encrypt/decrpyt your databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, You still need to compile in SQLCipher, but you can use FMDB. FMDB also provides a function to set the encryption key for the database
2. You can attach a non-encrypted database to an encrypted database (see http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#attach)
3. You will generally need to do an encryption registration with the DOC and then self-classify as mass market http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/question4.htm

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a simple tutorial on how to accomplish this, I was able to create one: http://www.guilmo.com/fmdb-with-sqlcipher-tutorial/

But the most important parts are, Opening your existing DB and attaching a new encrypted one. Then setting the key in your FMDB connections.

**SQLCipher - Encrypting the database**

```
// Import sqlite3.h in your AppDelegate
#import <sqlite3.h>

// Set the new encrypted database path to be in the Documents Folder
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *ecDB = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"encrypted.sqlite"];

// SQL Query. NOTE THAT DATABASE IS THE FULL PATH NOT ONLY THE NAME
const char* sqlQ = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE '%@' AS encrypted KEY 'secretKey';",ecDB] UTF8String];

sqlite3 *unencrypted_DB;    
if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &unencrypted_DB) == SQLITE_OK) {

    // Attach empty encrypted database to unencrypted database
    sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, sqlQ, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // export database
    sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Detach encrypted database
    sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "DETACH DATABASE encrypted;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_close(unencrypted_DB);
}
else {
    sqlite3_close(unencrypted_DB);
    NSAssert1(NO, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(unencrypted_DB));
}

self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"encrypted.sqlite"];
```

Note that we set 2 parameters in SQL Query, the DATABASE and the KEY. The DATABASE should be the **full path** to the encrypted database you want to create, in this case, string ecDB, and the KEY parameter is the key that’s going to be use to ENCRYPT your database, so choose a strong one

Now on your FMDB functions, call **[db setKey:@"strongKey"]** after every time you open the db.

```
// FMDatabase Example
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDatabasePath]];
[db open];
[db setKey:@"secretKey"];


// FMDatabaseQueue Exmple
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:[self getDatabasePath]];

[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
    [db setKey:@"secretKey"];
    ...
}];
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I ran into your tutorial a few weeks ago and saved it for later viewing and this morning I noticed that the website is down?   Is it possible for you to check on the site or post the tutorial another way?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @valosip I was changing servers, DNS should be propagating soon and the link will get back to working.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up finding a cached copy to get me going!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am using swift and following is the code I follow. But I have one problem the encrypted.sqlite file I can open with SQLiteBrowser what I was wrong here.

```
 var db: COpaquePointer = nil;
        let databasePath = FileUtils.getPath("data.db")
        var ecDB = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("encrypted.sqlite")
  let result = String.fromCString("ATTACH DATABASE \(ecDB) AS encrypted KEY TaP")
if (sqlite3_open(databasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
 sqlite3_exec(db, result!, nil, nil, nil);
 sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');", nil, nil, nil);
 sqlite3_exec(db, "DETACH DATABASE encrypted;", nil, nil, nil);
sqlite3_close(db);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_close(db);
            sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        }
```